# How to draw custom pin with Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Tags: c#, drawing, shapes

Hello I am trying to develop multiplatform application and I want to render shapes on my map.

I am able to render png files and etc, but is it possible to draw custom shapes created programatically?
I followed this example [XFGoogleMapSample](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/XFGoogleMapSample/CustomPinsPage.xaml.cs), but I am not able to create with PCL project.

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to draw lines (polylines) and shapes (polygons and circles), which can be drawn programmatically and interactive.

Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps/blob/master/XFGoogleMapSample/XFGoogleMapSample/ShapesPage.xaml.cs) which demonstrates the API.

Comment: Thank you steve but, I need to have it clickable so it should be still Pin.